# Time only in c#

Tags: c#

In C#

```
DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
```

gives the current date and time. I need only the **current time**. If I use string, it is possible like:

```
string time=DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Is it possible to get only the time portion of `DateTime` without going through a `string`?

Comment: Did you try it? (hint: Yes, that will work)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: The question he seems to be asking is how do I get just the time without converting to a string.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current time in a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) by accessing [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx), like this:

```
TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Now `time` will represent the amount of time that passed since midnight.

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the-box type that holds just a time. You could use `TimeSpan`, and even the .NET framework does at parts (for example `DateTime.TimeOfDay`), however I think that `TimeSpan` is really serving a different purpose.

`TimeSpan`, to quote MSDN, simply "measures a time interval". That could easily be longer than the hours, minutes, seconds, etc. that make up a day (i.e. 24 hours in sum). And indeed the `TimeSpan` structure provides for that, having properties like `Days`, for example.

Thus, I think `TimeSpan` is not a very good fit to represent the time of day (which I assume you mean when saying "current time").

That brings us to another problem. What exactly is the "current time"? As I said, I assume that you mean the current time as in "the current time of day". But current time could also mean the current (elapsed) time since some particular point in time in the past.

Granted, all that can get pretty theoretic or even rhetoric and does not really help you.

I would just use `DateTime`. Where you actually care about the "time" value, just only use the time portion (like you have shown, you known about, with your `ToString` example). Although, depending on what you need the time for, you might resort to the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property instead of simply formatting it as a string (unless of course that is what you need).

Finally, you could also resort to third party libraries like [Node Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), that do provide types for time only (like `LocalTime`).

Answer (score -1):

```
string time = string.Format("{0:hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);
```